# Looping through AJAX and callbacks in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm currently doing an AJAX call with jquery and callback functions to retrieve a result outside of the AJAX call and I am having trouble in attempting to use a loop to printout more data from my json file (ticker.json) provided here:

```
{
    "test": {
        "msgOne": [
            "Remote One",
            "Remote Two",
            "Remote Three"
        ],
        "msgTwo": "Remote2",
        "msgThree": "Remote3"
    }
}
```

My code is also below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Weather Data for Emergency Models</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<script Language="JavaScript">

    function hmm(callback) {

        $.ajax({
            url : 'ticker.json',               //   ___ |I want to loop this
            dataType: 'json',                  //   |   |index as a variable  
            success: function(response) {      //   v   
                result = response['test']['msgOne'][2];
                callback(result);
            }
        });

    }

    hmm(function(result) {
        document.write(result);  //currently outputs as "Remote Three"
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main problem is that I want to continue as asynchronous using the callback functions and loop through the "msgOne" array in the json file and print out all three results to the webpage sequentially. I have tried introducing a for-loop in multiple places previously, but I keep getting errors. I realize there are other ways to do this, but under the wanted conditions (asynchronous & callback functions because I want to eventually apply this to jsonp for json files found on multiple websites on a list), is there a way to do this? I ultimately want to modify the given code to deal with arrays and more complex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -
do this in your `success`

```
success: function(response) {      
  callback(response);
}
```

and in your `function`

```
hmm(function(result) {
    $.each(result.test.msgOne,function(i,v){
     document.write(v);
    });
});
```

Comment: One more question: if I wanted to loop through the AJAX call for an array representing my URL, how could I do that? (Assuming the json files of the URL were of the same structure just with different names)

Comment: `loop through the AJAX call` ? i didn't get what you want. Can you make it more clear with an example

Comment: Yeah, let's say I have a predetermined array called myURL and I want to loop through the ajax call such that each time the ajax call occurs, it happens with a different url from myURL, consequently yielding a different response in the callback.

Comment: That can be done easily. But i cant update my answer coz that seems out of context of your question, although i would suggest you to post a new question and provide me the link so that i can answer that there.

Comment: Try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574047/looping-through-the-url-in-an-ajax-call-in-jquery and thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Assuming response['test']['msgOne'] is an array

```
 success: function(response) {
                  $.each(response['test']['msgOne'], callback);
            }



hmm(function(i, result) {
        document.write(result);  //currently outputs as "Remote Three"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ticker.json',               //   ___ |I want to loop this
        dataType: 'json',                  //   |   |index as a variable  
        success: function(response) {      //   v   
            var result = response['test']['msgOne'];
            $.each(result,callback ).   

        }
    }); 
  function callback(index ,data){
   document.write(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me iterate through div rows, pull their data-id atribute and retrieve data from an ajax call using that data id. There happened to be 40+ ajax calls to itterate through. I have to leave them async true but watterfall the calls so as not to overload the server. I also used PHP to retrieve cached data and converted the PHP cached array to a javascript object:

```
 public static function load_footer_js_css() {
        $screen = get_current_screen();

        $whitelist = array('post','page');

        if(!isset($screen) || !in_array($screen->post_type , $whitelist )) {
            return;
        }

        $transient = get_transient( 'inbound_ga_post_list_cache' );
        $js_array = json_encode($transient);


        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php
            echo "var cache = JSON.parse('". $js_array . "');\n";
            ?>

            function inbound_ga_listings_lookup( cache, post_ids, i , callback , response ) {

                if (!post_ids[i]){
                    return true;
                }

                if (typeof response == 'object' && response  ) {
                    jQuery('.td-col-impressions[data-post-id="' + post_id + '"]').text(response['impressions']['current']['90']);
                    jQuery('.td-col-visitors[data-post-id="' + post_id + '"]').text(response['visitors']['current']['90']);
                    jQuery('.td-col-actions[data-post-id="' + post_id + '"]').text(response['actions']['current']['90']);
                }

                if (i == 0) {
                    post_id = post_ids[0];
                    i++;

                } else {
                    post_id = post_ids[i];
                    i++;
                }

                if (typeof cache[post_id] != 'undefined') {
                    jQuery( '.td-col-impressions[data-post-id="' + post_id + '"]').text( cache[post_id].impressions.current['<?php echo self::$range; ?>'] );
                    jQuery( '.td-col-visitors[data-post-id="' + post_id + '"]').text(cache[post_id].visitors.current['<?php echo self::$range; ?>']);
                    jQuery( '.td-col-actions[data-post-id="' + post_id + '"]').text(cache[post_id].actions.current['<?php echo self::$range; ?>']);
                } else {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        data: {
                            action: 'inbound_load_ga_stats',
                            post_id: post_id
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: true,
                        timeout: 10000,
                        success: function (response) {

                            callback(cache, post_ids, i, callback , response);
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, err) {
                            response['totals'] = [];
                            response['totals']['impressions'] = 0;
                            response['totals']['visitors'] = 0;
                            response['totals']['actions'] = 0;
                            callback(cache, post_ids, i, callback , response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

                var post_ids = [];
                var i = 0
                jQuery( jQuery('.td-col-impressions').get() ).each( function( $ ) {
                    var post_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-post-id');
                    post_ids[i] = post_id;
                    i++;
                });

                inbound_ga_listings_lookup( cache, post_ids, 0 , inbound_ga_listings_lookup , null );
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```