# Looping through the URL in an AJAX call in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So I recently asked a question concerning looping through data in a json file from an asynchronous AJAX call in jquery that uses callback functions ([Looping through AJAX and callbacks in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573479/looping-through-ajax-and-callbacks-in-jquery)) and I got a lot of good help, but now I wonder if I were to have 3 different json files (same structure and naming convention, but holding slightly different data) and their URLs in an array called myURL, would there be a way to loop through the AJAX call for all three URLs and output each of their respective results on a webpage? Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Weather Data for Emergency Models</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<script Language="JavaScript">

    //New Array for my URLs
    var myURL =  ["ticker1.json","ticker2.json","ticker3.json"];

    function hmm(callback) {

        $.ajax({
            url : myURL[j],  //<<<---Want to loop through this array
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                    callback(response);
            }
        });

    }

    hmm(function(result) {
        $.each(result.test.msgOne,function(i,v){
        document.write(v);
        document.write('<br>');
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(var k=0,len=myURL.length; k<len; k++)   

            $.ajax({
                url : myURL[k++],  //<<<---Want to loop through this array
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                        callback(response);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Well, I just tried this and noticed a " { " is lacking on the top line. Even after inserting your code in and trying it, I am getting syntax error for the top line somewhere. Nevertheless it won't run. Any thoughts? I also rewrote it as: For(var k=0; k<myURL.length; k++){...

Comment: @ADT there was a typo For instead of for.

Comment: Ah...ok. Well, I just fixed that and it looks like I am only getting output from the first file on the screen. Any additional thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(myURL,function(i,url){
     hmm(url,function(result) {
         $.each(result.test.msgOne,function(i,v){
           document.write(v);
           document.write('<br>');
         });
     });
 });
```

And in your function -

```
function hmm(url,callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url : url,  
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                 callback(response);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I'm only getting output from the first file...any thoughts?